# Get time out error when client is connecting to server

Tags: android, linux, usb, client-server, portforwarding

I'm trying to do port forwarding between my linux machine and android device so that I can send data to each other through a usb. The port that i'm connecting them both to is 38300 and I have run this command in the terminal; ./adb forward tcp:38200 tcp:38200. I run the app and try to connect, but I get an connection has timed out message. Was wondering if anyone had a clue about this. I'm running the server on my android device as an app and the client on my pc machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open all ports on your Android, run(as root):

```
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

For complete info about iptables [read man](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html)